# How to share users device token in ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, devicetoken

I am trying to find a way to make it possible for the user to find their device token (for debugging reasons).

---

## I have tried this:

#### AppDelegate.h

```
...
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    NSString *token;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *token;
...
```

#### AppDelegate.m

```
...

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    _token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    _token = [_token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSUInteger lenthtotes = [_token length];
    NSUInteger req = 64;

    if (lenthtotes == req){
        NSLog(@"uploaded token: %@", _token);
        upload_token = _token;
    } else {
        _token = @"";
    }
    ...
```

#### ViewController.m

```
NSString *token;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    token = appDelegate.token;
    NSLog(token);
...
```

The log within the `AppDelegate` works fine and returns the device token.
But the log inside the `ViewController` returns nothing how come ?

Comment: In which method of ViewController you are calling token = appDelegate.token;

Comment: oh sorry. Hold on I will edit the question...

Comment: is it possible the token to arrive after you check for the value ? You can use KVO to know when the token is set, but don't set the _token ivar, use only properties.

Comment: try the same with some delay or maybe you might be having viewController reference in AppDelegate. have this functionality in a method of viewController and call it from AppDelegate after receiving token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal that you can't retrieve the token this way because in the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller you didn't get your token yet.
Instead of **retrieving it** from the `AppDelegate`, you should **push it**. I would use a notification for that :

#### AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [_token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSUInteger lenthtotes = [_token length];
    NSUInteger req = 64;
    if (lenthtotes == req) {
        NSLog(@"uploaded token: %@", token);
        NSNotification *notif = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"NEW_TOKEN_AVAILABLE" object:token];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notif];
    }
    ...
}
```

#### ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(tokenAvailableNotification:)
                                                 name:@"NEW_TOKEN_AVAILABLE"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)tokenAvailableNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSString *token = (NSString *)notification.object;
    NSLog(@"new token available : %@", token);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: You *must* also remove that observer in dealloc (mistakes like this is why I generally recommend against NSNotificationCenter).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to grab it from the notification delegate method:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    // No need to define backing variables
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *token;

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{
    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    self.token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
}
```

Note that you must be compiling with the provisioning profile that's associated with your APNS-enabled App ID. If APNS is not properly configured, you may not receive a token.

As a side note, there is no need to define instance variables when using properties. The compiler will handle setting up backing variables, and managing all of that; you simply define the @property and access it through the pre-defined setters and getters (self.variableName).